# What's the type of 2d array's element in c and c++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array, language-lawyer

e.g.

```
int arr[2][3] = ...
```

The type of `arr[0]` is

```
int (*)[3] // pointer to int[3], which is a pointer.
```

Or

```
int[3] // an array whose size is 3, which is an array.
```

Google tells me nothing about the question.

I know pointer and array are different types(derived types).

Maybe C and C++ treat it differently, I hope to see standard wording.

Comment: @coderredoc Thanks. I doubted it is about conversion between array and pointer but not sure. Now it is solved.

Comment: Happy learning and all the best.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`arr[0]` is of type `int [3]` which is not a pointer.

`int (*p)[3]` is of type `int(*)[3]` meaning pointer to an array of 3 elements.

Pointer is not array and array is not pointer.

Now when you pass this 2d array to a function (or any case where decaying occurs) then it ***decays into*** pointer to the first element which is `int (*)[3]`.

To be more clear in `C` 2d array  is nothing but array of arrays.

Dissecting

- `arr` is an array each of element of which is again an array with `3` elements.
- `arr[0]` in most of the cases (except `sizeof` etc) will decay into pointer to first element it contains which is an `int*`.
- `arr[0][0]` is an `int`.
- At last `&arr[0]` .. guess what? This is of type `int(*)[3]`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162259/discussion-on-answer-by-coderredoc-whats-the-type-of-2d-arrays-element-in-c-an).